# LaTeX: vectors with two heads on the right

Tags: amsmath

Is there a way to use something similar to `$\overrightarrow{V}$`,
namely `$\twoheadoverrightarrow{\delta}$` to get vectors with two heads?

While `\twoheadrightarrow` is defined, `\twoheadoverrightarrow` does not seem to be defined, so is there some work around?

Comment: TikZ can do that. Try the TikZ manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Ti*k*Z, just fiddling with the internal macros of the `amsmath` package:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\twoheadrightarrowfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\twoheadrightarrow
}
\newcommand*\twoheadleftarrowfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\twoheadleftarrow\relbar\relbar
}
\newcommand*\twoheadoverrightarrow{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\twoheadrightarrowfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\twoheadoverleftarrow{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\twoheadleftarrowfill@}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

In-line: \( \twoheadoverrightarrow{\alpha} + \twoheadoverleftarrow{\beta} \).
Now displayed, with an example of use in subscripts:
\[
    \twoheadoverrightarrow{\alpha} + \twoheadoverleftarrow{\beta}
        + X_{\twoheadoverrightarrow{\delta}}
\]

\end{document}
```